# How to overcome hardware limitations when reading/writing to a file.

Tags: java, file, file-io, filestream, bufferedreader

I was asked this question in an interview recently.

> Given an input file, a regex and an output file. Read the input file, match each line to the regex and write the matching lines to an output file.

I came up with the rough scheme of using a BufferedReader chained to a FileReader (to optimize Reads from the disk). I used a similar scheme for writing.

> The interviewer then said that this process takes 3 seconds to read a line from the file, 1 second to compare the regex with the line and another 5 seconds to write back. so it takes a total of 9 seconds per line. How can we improve this?

I suggested reading the entire file at once, processing it and writing the entire output file at once. However, I was told that won't help (Writing 1 line = 5 seconds, writing 2 lines = 10 seconds) .

> The interviewer further said that this is due to a hardware/ hard drive limitation. I was asked how I can improve my code to reduce the total seconds (currently 9 ) per line?

I could only think of buffered reading/ writing and could not find much on SO as well. Any thoughts ?

Comment: multihreading and synchronisation ? you would not have to wait 1 sec for regex processing and proceed with reading the next line. after regex has processing has terminated another thread witch is waiting for matching lines can write to output. but i doubt this last step would bring much improvment since you have one disc and it either reading or writing a one particular moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the interviewer was looking for a solution that performs reading/regex checking in parallel with writing the output. If you set up a work queue that you fill asynchronously by reading and filtering, and put writing in a separate thread, then the combined process would take five seconds per line, starting with the second line.

The assumption here is that reading, parsing, and writing can happen independently of each other. In this case, you can be reading line 2 while line 1 is being written: you need only four seconds to read and apply your regex, and you've got a whole five seconds before the writer is ready for the second line. The writing remains your bottleneck, but the whole process gets sped up by some 44%, which isn't bad.

Answer (score 0):

Well since the time for a read is fixed and the time for a write is fixed, the only option you have in this case is to change the nature of the regex bit.

You could write code to apply the regex test quickly without the overhead of all the clever things that regex can do.

If on the other hand the problem is that each IO request takes several seconds to be executed, but the limitation is not the actual drive, then have several readers reading simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Tough question, since we don't no much about the system.

My guess would be using threads/ async processing. Use one Thread to read and one to process an two or more for writing, thus reducing the time spent for IO Wait.

Let my try to convert this into an ASCII Chart:

- R/r means reading (3 Sec)
- P/p means processing (1 Sec)
- W/w means writing (5 Sec)

upper case letter mark the start, lower case letter mark continuing work. A ":" means thread is idle

```
Thread 1: RrrRrrRrrRrrRr
Thread 2: ...P..P..P..P.
Thread 3: ....Wwwww
Thread 4: .......Wwwww
```

With this setup the first batch is written back after 9 Seconds (not much to do here) but the second one completes after 12 Seconds. Single threaded the second one needs 18 Seconds total